# SequelizeJS - hasMany to hasMany on the same table with a join table

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

My problem is quite simple:

I got a table named **users**.
Those users can have a lot of contacts. Those contacts are other users.

So I have a table named **userHasContacts**, with the id of the owner (**userID**), and the id of the contact (**contactID**).
Both of those foreign keys are referencing **users** table.

Here is my beautiful diagram:

```
              ----------------  
______________|____      ____|____
| userHasContacts |      | users |
-------------------      ---------
| #userID         |      | id    |
| #contactID      |      ---------
-------------------          |
              |              |
              ----------------
```

In sequelize, in my logic, I would write:

```
Users.hasMany(Users, {foreignKey: 'userID', joinTableName: 'userHasContacts'} );
Users.hasMany(Users, {as: 'Contacts', foreignKey: 'contactID', joinTableName: 'userHasContacts'} );
```

But it seems like it doesn't work this way, and it's been 2 hours I am trying several ways to write this relation...

The only line that worked for me was

```
Users.hasMany(UserHasContacts, {foreignKey: 'contactID', joinTableName: 'userHasContacts'} );

UserHasContacts.findAndCountAll({ where: {userID: id} }).success( function(result) {        
    res.json(result);
});
```

But then I cannot join **users** table in my find query (via [Eager loading](http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#models-eager-loading)) and it simply returns the data inside **userHasContacts**.

If anyone got an hint, you are welcome!
Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since what you are trying to do is a self association you only need to call hasMany once, which will create a junction table

```
User.hasMany(User, { as: 'Contacts', joinTableName: 'userHasContacts'})
```

Which will create the userHasContacts table as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userHasContacts` (`userId` INTEGER , `ContactsId` INTEGER , `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`userId`,`ContactsId`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

To find users and their contacts you can then do:

```
User.find({ where: ..., include: [{model: User, as: 'Contacts'}]})
```